# Custom property in NavigationViewItem

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, navigationview

I'm creating a new grid in NavigationViewItem for notifications. But I don't understand how to create a 
`< NavigationViewItem.Notification visible="True" Text="12" >` property to use.

I created the design but the text is assigned to all items.
I would like to control the properties of notifications (Visible and Text)

[image]

How do I manage this?
Any help would be appreciated!

```
<Grid Visibility="Visible" CornerRadius="5, 5, 5, 5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="30" Background="#11FFFFFF" Opacity="1" Height="24" Margin="0,0,15,0">
 <TextBlock Text="17" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,1" Foreground="#FFC5C5C5"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes of course. I put the code in a text file and used Google Drive because there is a limitation here.

Link: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wxyjN0dVv0Eu-mioXA7twdH-TiSU2cQ7)

Answer (score 1):

> Custom property in NavigationViewItem

The default `NavigationViewItem` does not contain `Notification` property. You could use TempateControl to custom `NavigationViewItem` but it is complex. There is easy way implement it that process `Visibility` with `IValueConverter`.

```
    <Grid
        Width="200"
        Height="24"
        Margin="0,0,15,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Background="#11FFFFFF"
        CornerRadius="5, 5, 5, 5"
        Opacity="1"
        Visibility="{Binding MessgeCount, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"
        >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="0,0,0,1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Foreground="#FFC5C5C5"
            Text="{Binding MessgeCount}"
            />
    </Grid>
```

**VisibilityConverter**

```
public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if ((int)value == 0)
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Model class**

```
public class Category : CategoryBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tooltip { get; set; }
    public Symbol Glyph { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public int MessgeCount { get; set; }
}
```

This is code sample that you could [refer](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/NavigationViewItemsTest).